# How to use the Delete button as a shortcut in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, keyboard-shortcuts

I already have both regular and custom keyboard shortcuts enabled on my Gmail, but I'm unable to set a shortcut with the "Delete" button. I noticed the default configuration has a shortcut set to "ESC", so I tried to include "del", "Del" and "DEL", but none of them work. Other buttons, such as "d", work fine. Is it possible to use the "Delete" button as a custom shortcut?